# Using JSON.net define class with array in Dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, json, dictionary

I am trying to do the following inside a `Dictionary<string,string>`

```
{
    "name": "Bob Barker",
    "devName": "InformationServices",
    "ReturnedData": [{
        "level_heading": "blah1",
        "DeliverBestMedicalValue": "blah2",
        "level_question": "blah3"
    }]
}
```

I can add the **name** and **devName** just fine but I am unsure on how to go about adding the **ReturnedData** part of the array to the list so that it will return as the layout above?

Example code I am using:

```
febRecords.RootObject febRecordsData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<febRecords.RootObject>(serverResponse);
Dictionary<string,string> febFormData = new Dictionary<string,string>();

febFormData.Add("name", data.firstname.ToString());
febFormData.Add("devName", febData["Data"]["DevisionName"].ToString());
febFormData.Add("ReturnedData", ???); //<-this is where I am stuck

return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(febFormData, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
```

As you see, **febFormData.Add("ReturnedData", ???);** is the spot where I am stuck and dont really know what to do in order to get the dictionary to output the correct JSON format like I want.

Any help would be great!

**update**

Would this be how the class needs to look?

```
public class theOutput
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string devName { get; set; }
    public List<string> ReturnedData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: which data do you want?

Comment: Why are you creating a dictionary piece by piece instead of using a class with properties like `name`, `devName` etc ? On the other hand, you could start by *deserializing* the sample Json and observe the resulting object. `ReturnedData` looks like an array of objects with properties `level_heading` etc

Comment: I'm not sure, but, try `new Dictionary<string,string>();` change to `new Dictionary<string,object>();` and then for *ReturnedData* use `Dictionary<string,string>();`... for example : `Dictionary<string,string> retData = new Dictionary<string,string>(); retData.Add("level_heading", "blah1"); ...` and then `febFormData.Add("ReturnedData",retData);` ... i using `vb.net`, I suppose this is correct conversion to `c#`.

Comment: @DanielA.White I am wondering how to place the data into the Dictionary so that it will format the way I am looking to format it in the first JSON example in my OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Panagiotis Kanavos you'd really be better off having .NET entity to match your JSON data. For example:

```
// propertyname attributes can be ignored if property names 
// match the json data property names 1:1

[JsonObject]
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        ReturnedData = new List<ReturnedData>();
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "devName")]
    public string DevName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ReturnedData")]
    public List<ReturnedData> ReturnedData { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject]
public class ReturnedData
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "level_heading")]
    public string LevelHeading { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "DeliverBestMedicalValue")]
    public string DeliverBestMedicalValue { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "level_question")]
    public string LevelQuestion { get; set; }
}
```

This would make conversion to/from JSON that much easier.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSome()
{
    string json = @"{
        ""name"": ""Bob Barker"",
        ""devName"": ""InformationServices"",
        ""ReturnedData"": [{
            ""level_heading"": ""blah1"",
            ""DeliverBestMedicalValue"": ""blah2"",
            ""level_question"": ""blah3""
        }]
    }";

    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
    Assert.IsTrue(JToken.DeepEquals(JObject.Parse(json), JObject.FromObject(obj)));
}
```

---

You can always generate stubs from you JSON data using e.g. http://json2csharp.com/

Here "live" .NET fiddle, too https://dotnetfiddle.net/9ACddp